# How to choose manual treadmill for rucking

Tags: walking, treadmill

I would like to have manual treadmill at home for rucking.

So far I have opportunity to test only one model. The model I have tested has fixed incline (kind of steep one). The experience was really disappointing. There was some kind of "difficulty" setting. Almost any settings leads to need of sprinting (or grabbing the rails) to prevent falling off. The most "stiff" settings allow me to walk, but in pace much higher than is suitable for rucking (or even walking) at my fitness level.

Major questions:

*Are the manual treadmills designed to be used for moderate pace walking without touching the rails?*

If yes, then I have few minor questions:

1. Should I search for manual treadmill with adjustable incline?
2. Is there some norm for difficulty range?
3. Is the difficulty influenced by my weight?
4. What other parameters are important?
5. Anything else I should now?

Notes:

1. I would probably be happy just with "walking" if rucking would not be possible.
2. Most of the year I weight 80-90kg. With rucking load up to 40kg, I should not exceed 130kg total.
3. I know that it is possible to ruck/walk outdoors. I do that fairly often (almost daily). So answers about why I should walk outdoors do not help with my question at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into a curved manual treadmill.
They are not cheap. I've never tried rucking on the one I've used in a gym.
[Good summary of available models](https://sprintcoach.com/2018/01/08/my-quest-to-find-the-perfect-curved-manual-treadmill/)

Comment: Thanks for an interesting direction to look. But as you said, they cost like 15-25 times more than manual treadmill with slope. And seems to me that they are way too big and bulky for home usage. However, If you see some interesting smaller models, I would be happy if you provide a reference in your answer.